# Why React can not find "this" in event handler

Tags: reactjs

All:

I am pretty new to React, when I try to make a very simple component like a inputbox with a label, which the label can change according to the input of input box.

```
class App extends React.Component {
    constructor() {
        super();
        this.name = "World";
    }
    changeName(e){
        var nameinput = this.refs.nameinput;
        this.name = nameinput.value;
    }
    render(){
        return  (
            <div>
                <input ref="nameinput" onChange={this.changeName} />
                Hello, {this.name}!
            </div>
            );
    }
}
```

Currently the problem is in changeName() function, there is no reference to App( when I print out `this`, it is undefined) **I wonder how can I get the reference to that inputbox with something like refs.nameinput.value**

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to bind your event handler:

```
<input ref="nameinput" onChange={this.changeName.bind(this)}/>
```

See this question for more details on `this`:

[How to access the correct `this` context inside a callback?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20279484/how-to-access-the-correct-this-context-inside-a-callback)

Comment: thanks, now it works, but I wonder why the render function does not get called, does that mean I have to manually call this.setState() everytime I run a event ahndler? I am kinda wonder if my state data structure is very deep, how do I write it in setState() ( like this.AA.BB.CC.DD.XXX.name)?

Comment: You will need to call `setState`. You will need to move `name` into the `state` property of your component. `setState` shallowly merges with the existing state, but it won't merge deeply nested objects (you can however manually merge your nested data with changes using `Object.assign`). I'd recommend trying to flatten your data and look into immutability.

Comment: Thanks, good idea, I will read that

Answer (score 1):

Or you can bind it in your constructor

```
constructor() {
        super();
        this.name = "World";
        this.changeName = this.changeName.bind(this);
    }
```

Comment: now it works, but I wonder why the render function does not get called, does that mean I have to manually call this.setState() everytime I run a event ahndler?  I am kinda wonder if my state data structure is very deep, how do I write it in setState()?